# $\epsilon-N$ verification that $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{n}{n^2 + 1} = 0$

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

Can someone please check if the following proof of $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{n}{n^2 + 1} = 0$ is correct?

---

Let $\epsilon > 0$ and choose $N = \lceil1/\epsilon\rceil + 1$. Then for all $n > N$, we have

$$\left| \frac{n}{n^2 + 1} - 0\right|$$

$$= \frac{n}{n^2 + 1} \leq \frac{n}{n^2} = \frac{1}{n}.$$

But since $n > N = \lceil{1/\epsilon}\rceil + 1$, we have $n > 1/\epsilon$; or equivalently, $\epsilon > 1/n$. Therefore,

$$\frac{1}{n} 
< \epsilon,$$

as desired.

Comment: Should $\frac{n}{n}$ be $\frac{n}{n^2}$? Looks good otherwise.

Comment: yes you are correct

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your proof is correct except a typo in $$ \frac{n}{n^2 + 1} \leq \frac{n}{n} \leq \frac{1}{n}$$

Please fix it to $$\frac{n}{n^2 + 1} < \frac{n}{n^2} = \frac{1}{n}$$

and go from there.